# Encoding is larger than the original text: How to take strings of zeros and ones and write them as actual bytes to file

Tags: c++, encoding, compression

I have an implementation of LZ77(sliding window) in `C++` that is able to successfully take a file and output and encoding of 0s 1s to another file. Only problem is the **output file** is bigger than the **original**.

I have figured out that this is because I am using strings to represent the bit strings and am writing these strings to a file.

I am wondering how can I take these string tokens of zeros ones and write them as bytes to the file to save myself space.

Comment: Most languages have *bitwise operators* to handle bits, allowing you to set, clear or toggle arbitrary bits on integer values.

Comment: First of all, stop using strings to store binary data. Then you don't have to do anything at all to try to fix the problems you create when you try to use strings to work with binary data. And there won't be a ""Second of all". :-) (And if you're corrupting the file by converting binary to string, and ending up with a different file than you had at the source, you've not *successfully* done anything.)

Comment: @KenWhite yes it was probably a bad design choice. but at this point i am stuck with it is there anything i can do? I never said I was converting binary to string.

Comment: You've converted one bit (a 0 or 1) to 8 bits (a "0" or "1"). That's going to take some work. You're going to have to do a lot of bit-shifting and toggling to fix each single byte of the file (converting 32 characters to 32 bits)..

Answer (score 0):

In the end here is what i came up with

```
    unsigned char str_to_byte(std::string s){
    std::bitset<8> b(s);
    return static_cast<unsigned char> (b.to_ulong());
}


    void write(std::string s,std::ostream& out)
{
    size_t len = s.length();
    std::string tstring;
    unsigned char c;
    if (len < 8){
        tstring = pad_string(s, 8);
        c = str_to_byte(tstring);
        //std::cout << tstring << std::endl;
        out << c;
        return;
    }
    size_t i = 0 ;
    for (; i < len; i+=8){
        tstring = s.substr(i,8);
        //std::cout << tstring << std::endl;
        c = str_to_byte(tstring);
        out << c;
    }
    if (i != len){
        i = i-8;
        tstring = pad_string(s.substr(i,8),8);
        //std::cout << tstring << std::endl;
        c = str_to_byte(tstring);
        out << c;
    }
}
```